# sql select and replace

Tags: sql

I have a query that will show all the client information, and there is a column called sex, which 1 is female, 0 is male. How can I do another select on this result, that turn all the female record, turn the 1 to 100, male to 101?  ( 1 and 0 in the first query, they are bit, in the second they are nvarchar) (Mssql)

```
select * from tblClientInfo

001 Derrick  0
002 Mary     1
```

then, turn it to

```
001 Derrick  100
002 Mary     101
```

Comment: if I ma ask, why is the new column to be a varchar, and not some flavor of Number?  Also, your example doesn't match with your stated result... you said you want the males to become 101, but in your sample out put you have the male as 100

Comment: That was a typo sir

Comment: And the data type it doesn't matter. I am adding this because I grab these from different database , one is using lookuptable, male is like id = 100, female is 101. but previous design was a bit, male is 0, female is 1.

Comment: I was asking because of how I was going to phrase my response.  Granted, I don't know which type of DB you are using, so I cant give you a specific syntax, but if the data type doesn't matter, then if you make the new field some form of number, you might be able to get away with `UPDATE new_table SET new_field = to_number(old_field) +100`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when male = 0 then '100' else '101' end)
```